# How to invoke secured webservice from ADF JAX-WS proxy client

Tags: oracle-adf, adfs2.0

We are trying to implement ADF JAX-WS proxy client to access secured webservice(E-Business Suite). How to pass username/password?

If I run without passing it, I am getting the below error
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Missing  in SOAP Header

Comment: Use the login method provided by the web service. This is also handy: http://biemond.blogspot.be/2009/04/jax-ws-web-service-proxy-client-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Google to ask that question? I did and this is what it found in 0.02 seconds

http://biemond.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/jax-ws-web-service-proxy-client-and.html